# Single Graphana Dashboard for multiple Prometheus target

Tags: docker, prometheus

I've installed prometheus+graphana+cadvisor+nodeexporter+caddy on one ubuntu machine as detailed [here](https://stefanprodan.com/2016/a-monitoring-solution-for-docker-hosts-containers-and-containerized-services/).

The graphana graphs load well, I'm able to see all the metrics in graphs as expected. Now, I decided to monitor another server using this as central prothemeus, and the new server would have nodeexporter service running. Below is docker-compose.yml for it:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:v1.0.1
    container_name: nodeexporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

The prometheus.yml file on ubuntu has in its scraping targets both the machines:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'nodeexporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100', 'ec2-XX-XX:9100']
```

Now, when I open the graphs, it shows weird message "Only queries that return single series/table is supported" in some graphs.

[image: Graphana error with multiple target]

Ideally, I'd want to be able to choose the target via some drop down and then see its Docker Host Dashboard. Is there any way that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. The thing is called [Templates and Variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/).

You may want to make data source selectable first by defining a variable of type [datasource](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-data-source-variable/).

Then you define some query variables by some label, typically `job`and/or `instance` with something like `label_values(up{job=~"$jobs"}, instance)`.

Then you apply these variables in your query filters like `wmi_system_threads{instance=~"$server"}`.

Check out live example here: https://play.grafana.org/d/000000063/prometheus-templating?orgId=1

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult to actually understand how to configure. Any links and examples with complete clarity would help. Thanks

Comment: I'm still getting that error "Only queries that return single series/table is supported" on few graphs after configuring the variable correctly. Why can that happen?

Comment: You can see from the Memory Graph that you have your metrics duplicated. I still suspect you haven't applied a filter to your queries as proposed above: `wmi_system_threads{instance=~"$server"}`, where `server` is the variable name you choose when specifying a variable.

Comment: You can add something like `{{instance}}` to Memory Graph, Legend field of the query and you'll see if the metric is displayed for multiple instances.
Or click Prometheus button in Query pane and inspect the full set of labels in Prometheus Console.